# How to install the latest g++ version on CentOS

Tags: centos, installation, yum, gcc

I tried `yum install gcc-c++`, however, the repos have an old version (4.1) which causes lots of problems and stops me from building a library. I would like to update it to latest. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're referring to CentOS 5.x, based on the version number in your post. You can upgrade to `gcc44-c++`, which is a slightly-newer version 4.4. This is available in the base repo using yum.

Try `yum install gcc44-c++`.

Once installed, the executable you'd use will be `/usr/bin/g++44` instead of `/usr/bin/g++`.

Comment: this is great, so much easier than I expected to be...